# Warning: Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$playid in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla4\components\com_football\tmpl\team\default.php on line 120

Tags: php, mysql, joomla

So I am building a Joomla component which will be like a football league manager.  In the DB I have a table with #__football_team and #__football_player in which I am trying to display the players on the team.  When trying to pull and assign in the model view using:

```
    if (isset($this->_item->playid) && $this->_item->playid != '') {
        if (is_object($this->_item->playid)) {
            $this->_item->playid = ArrayHelper::fromObject($this->_item->playid);
        }

        $values = (is_array($this->_item->playid)) ? $this->_item->playid : explode(',',$this->_item->playid);

        $textValue = array();

        foreach ($values as $value) {
            $db    = Factory::getDbo();
            $query = "SELECT * 
                        FROM #__football_players 
                        WHERE `active` = '1' 
                        AND #__football_team.teamid LIKE '" . $value . "'";

            $db->setQuery($query);
            $results = $db->loadObject();

            if ($results) {
                $textValue[] = $results->lname;
            }
        }

        $this->_item->playid = !empty($textValue) ? implode(', ', $textValue) : $this->_item->playid;
    }
    return $this->_item;
}
```

But I keep getting an error that the property is undefined:

> Warning: Undefined property: Joomla\CMS\Object\CMSObject::$playid in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla4\components\com_football\tmpl\team\default.php on line 120

Comment: Looks like you create `$this->_item->playid` inside an IF, but you reference it later in the code, outside that IF. So one would guess when you get the error the `if (is_object($this->_item->playid)) {` is not true, therefore `$this->_item->playid` is not created

Comment: `isset($this->_item->playid) && $this->_item->playid != ''` is more simply expressed as `!empty($this->_item->playid)`.  `fromObject()` unconditionally returns an array, so the conditional explode is pointless. https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.Utilities.ArrayHelper.html  You should not be creating database objects inside of a loop, just make one instance and keep re-using it.  You are not using Joomla's query builder methods. You are not using wildcards around your value, so `LIKE` looks ill-suited. I believe this whole task can be done in a single query.

Comment: Please ask all of your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.  `loadColumn` seems appropriate to implement: https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Single_Column_Results